# Difference Between Package Versions

Tags: version

I got two lists with package versions and I want to determine which packages are newer. In some cases there are packages like this:

**Old List**

PackageX 1.3-r0
PackageY 1.5-r85

**New List**

PackageX 1.3
PackageY 1.5

It seams that the `-r` suffix is missing in the new list for every package. What assumption can be made about the packages in the new list? Are they newer or older? What difference between them can be expected?

Comment: -r sounds like the release-candidate to me, but i've never seen a software which needs 85 release-candidates before the final version is finished, so i'm not sure about this.

Comment: Which kind of packages are referred to?  If they are package versions of distribution packages, there is always a clear rule which is newer (e.g. in Debian, the package in the old list would be newer than the version from the new list).

Comment: It seems that these packages are from the Yocto project. Edit: I see... thats only a framework for creating custom Linux distros...

Comment: Most of these projects will have release notes on in the source or on mailing lists. Try checking there. I wish I could give a better answer, but I think @tkausl is probably the best.